# What is the precise definition of a moon?

Tags: natural-satellites

With the recent discovery of Saturn's 20 new moons (elevating its position on the rank of planets with the greatest amount of moons, surpassing Jupiter), it makes me wonder: what are the requirements a celestial body has to meet to be considered a moon?

Are there any limitations in size, shape or even orbit?